# Apps showcase dissapeared from foursquare website

Tags: foursquare

recently there was a section at foursquare.com website with the list of all applications. However now it is not accessible for some reason. I even have the link stored in Google Search results with guide to foursquare "page not found" error:

https://foursquare.com/app/jet_lovers__your_flight_club

Does anyone have the idea what happened?

Answer (score 0):

We took it down to make some improvements -- a new version will be up eventually.